# Django child model data not saving with Ajax raising ValueError: Data didn't validate

Tags: python, django

I am trying to save data in a pair of related models in my Django application using Ajax. Though the parent table data is saved, I am unable to save data in the child model. The system gives off the following error message:

**Error:** `ValueError: The mappedTargFields could not be created because the data didn't validate.`

**How do I save data in child table** as well? Even with extensive search I am unable to find a solution to save inline formsets data (which I normally do using CBV + management form). Or is it not possible to save formset data using jQuery/Ajax?

Given below are the relevant codes:

### views.py

```
def SaveMapAjax(request, object_id=False):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        qs_targ_model_form = mappedTargModelForm(request.POST)
        target_field_formset = CreateMappedTargFieldsFormset(request.POST)
        
        if qs_targ_model_form.is_valid():
            qs_targ_model_form.save()
            target_field_formset = CreateMappedTargFieldsFormset(request.POST, instance=qs_targ_model_form, prefix='')
            target_field_formset.save()
            msg='Data saved!!!'
            return JsonResponse(msg, safe=False)
        else:
            msg= 'Error occured in save!'

    else:
        qs_targ_model_form = mappedTargModelForm()
        target_field_formset = CreateMappedTargFieldsFormset(instance=qs_targ_model_form)

    return JsonResponse(msg, safe=False)
```

### Formset

```
CreateMappedTargFieldsFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    mappedTargModel,            # Parent table
    mappedTargFields,           # Child table
    form=mappedTargFieldsForm,      # Modelform on Child table
    extra=2,
    can_delete=False, min_num=1, validate_min=True)
```

### Template

```
<!--html-->
    
<form action="" method="POST" class="form" id="dataMapperForm">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ target_model_form.as_p }}
    <div class="col-md-12 text-nowrap" style="font-family:'Courier New'">
        {{ target_field_formset.management_form }}
    </div>
</form>


<!--The ajax part-->
    
<script>

$(function() {
    $('#dataMapperForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        var frm = $('#dataMapperForm');
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{% url 'save_mapper' %}',
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('Success!!');
                    $("#dataMapperForm")[0].reset();
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log('Error');
            },
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

*Edit:*

Following is the error it is throwing on `target_field_formset.errors`:

```
[{'mapper_item': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.'], 'mapper_header': ['The inline value did not match the parent instance.']}, {'mapper_item': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.'], 'mapper_header': ['The inline value did not match the parent instance.']}, {'mapper_item': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.'], 'mapper_header': ['The inline value did not match the parent instance.']}]
```

*Edit2:*

On printing the serialized data to the console I am getting the follwoing:

```
&mapper_doc_type=MAPPER                       // Parent model field
&mapper_name=Test                             // Parent model field
&mapper_target_model=employee                 // Parent model field
&mapper_hdr_tab-TOTAL_FORMS=3
&mapper_hdr_tab-INITIAL_FORMS=0
&mapper_hdr_tab-MIN_NUM_FORMS=1
&mapper_hdr_tab-MAX_NUM_FORMS=1000
&mapper_hdr_tab-0-mapper_item=name                 // Child model "pk"
&mapper_hdr_tab-0-mapper_header=name               // Child model "fk" field
&mapper_hdr_tab-0-mapped_field=name               // Child model field
&mapper_hdr_tab-0-mapped_field_col_name=NAME
```

To my mind, value assignment to `mapper_item` should be an **integer** and not **name** as it shows above. Similarly for the next item `mapper_header` which should be the primary key of the parent table and not **name**.

Something I am doing here is very wrong.

Comment: @Andrey Maslov -  I have added the error as an **edit**. You may add your comments under my question, just in case. Here `mapper_item` is the `primary_key` of the child model **mappedTargFields**. `mapper_header` is the field in child model pointing to the parent table **mappedTargModel**.

Comment: we have validation errors, but don't have any form or model included.

Answer (score 0):

you check that form `is_valid`, but don't check that formset `is_valid`

```
if qs_targ_model_form.is_valid():
            qs_targ_model_form.save()
            target_field_formset = CreateMappedTargFieldsFormset(request.POST, instance=qs_targ_model_form, prefix='')
            if target_field_formset.is_valid():
               target_field_formset.save()
               msg='Data saved!!!'
               return JsonResponse(msg, safe=False)
            else:
               msg = 'Formset is not valid'
        else:
            msg= 'Error occured in save!'
```

Comment: you are talking about error capturing. what about the issue at hand?

Comment: you have error **Error: ValueError: The mappedTargFields could not be created because the data didn't validate.**. it sais that you tried to save formset without validating it. i showed you code where i validated formset before saving

Comment: the err is about an inherent problem wherein data validation is not happening despite all mandatory data being there in the formset. what you are doing is simply **error trapping**. which does not solve the proble. it is somewhere else in my code.

Comment: `target_field_formset = CreateMappedTargFieldsFormset(request.POST, instance=qs_targ_model_form, prefix='')`
            `target_field_formset.save()` you create formset and then trying to save it. you can't do that without validating it. just add one line between them `target_field_formset.is_valid()`

Comment: validate what? there is nothing to validate. all field values are strings. all mandatory fields are filled in.

Comment: django will not save your formset without that line. try it

Comment: just by an err trapping it would not solve the problem and guess what, ** it doesn't**. the error is pointing to an action which is post-mortem, and not ante...

Comment: `target_field_formset = CreateMappedTargFieldsFormset(instance=qs_targ_model_form)`  i think mistake could be there, replace with `CreateMappedTargFieldsFormset(instance=qs_targ_model_form.instance)`

Comment: Okay ... with this new approach `instance=qs_targ_model_form.instance` it goes into the `else: 'msg = 'Formset is not valid''` segment. So all along it's been that there is something wrong with the **formset**. My question is how do I tackle this? If you think including my **models** would help you get to the bottom of it, I will edit my question to include them.

Comment: instead of just sending msg = 'Formset is not valid', you better show something more informative like target_field_formset.errors, target_field_formset.non_field_errors.

Comment: you may check my edits and comment against my question body